# Are es6 modules incompatible with Polymer 1.x?

Tags: ecmascript-6, polymer, es6-modules

I'm trying to convert some legacy Polymer 1.x javascript into an es6 module to make the code a bit easier to test. I've encountered an odd error where this.$ is sometimes undefined. I have found that including an empty script (  `<script> </script>` ) seems to alleviate the problem in Chrome, but not Firefox. Adding a timer so the imported code from the module takes longer to load also helps in Chrome, but not Firefox. I'm not sure if the empty script is magical, or if there is some asynchronous event and the empty script is just slowing things down for long enough for the event to finish.

Here is a bit of the dom I'm using:

```
  <script> </script>
  <script type="module">
    import buildView from "./scripts/live-production-view.js";
    buildView();
  </script>
```

and this is the javascript it loads:

```
export default () =>
  Polymer(Object.assign(
    shiftSelectionActions('/data/live-production', Polymer),
    { is, properties, observers, ready, detached },
  ));
```

The error occurs when trying to access this.$ in the ready function (returns undefined).